# How to add field type as button in reactable library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am using `reactable` to draw table in my react app.

I get data from server in `json object` and pass this data to `Table`

```
render(){
    return(            
        <Table className="table" data= {this.state.content}  
        defaultSort={{column: 'account_status', direction: 'desc'}}
        />
        )}
```

This works fine and draws the table like this.

[image]

Now i want to add 2 buttons with each row, `Approve/reject`.

I want to know the possibility of adding buttons with each row when using `reactable`

Comment: There are instructions for customising the table on [their documentation](https://glittershark.github.io/reactable/). Have you tried that?

Comment: @SamiHult : Yes i looked into that, and it looks like if i go for customization, then i need to provide data for each cell individually, i need to provide a complete data object to the table.

Comment: That unfortunately seems to be the only way. You would still gain the sorting, pagination etc. features from the component.